# Nested http calls not working with ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, observable

I have a one parent http request where it needs to be done first(getTrialForPatient) and with the response i need to do two more http requests which needs to be paralel.(getDailyQuestionaireData, getStartEndQuestionaireData)
I tried to use forkJoin but couldnt succeed. Any idea where i m doing wrong ?

```
private _trialListPoll$ = timer(0, this.listRequestInterval).pipe(switchMap(()=>{
    return this.trialDataService.getTrailForPatient(this.patientId).pipe(map(data=>{
      if(data && data.result && data.result.length > 0){
        const trial = data.result[0] as TrialPhase;
        this.trialId = trial.trialId;

      return data.result[0];
    }));
    }
  ),switchMap(()=>forkJoin( this.trialDataService.getDailyQuestionaireData(this.trialId),this.trialDataService.getStartEndQuestionaireData(this.trialId)),tap(([res1, res2])=> {
    console.log(res1,res2,"works ? ")
    }))

    ,share());
```

Comment: Are you sure that both Obervables returned from `this.trialDataService` complete?

Comment: yeah, they are basic http calls

Comment: Are you missing the []? Should be `forkJoin([...])`? If that's not the issue, can you provide a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue?